# How to get out of(block) nested Iterators once value is found?

Tags: scala, iterator

I have some code like this with nested Iterators. I want to stop, get out of foreach/map and return(value) if the find returns and Some(value), and continue to incase of None. What's the right approach here?

**Edit:** Here's the full function

```
Line Schema: line_id, name

Stop Schema: stop_id, x, y

Time Schema: line_id, stop_id, time
```

Given time and x,y I want to find line_id and name. So for the time being Im stuck with getting valueWhichImTryingToGet.

```
  def findVehicle(time: String, x: String, y: String) = {
    val stopIter = Source.fromFile("stops.csv").getLines().drop(1)
    val stopCols = stopIter.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
    val stopIds = stopCols.filter(arr => arr(1) == x && arr(2) == y)

     val valueWhichImTryingToGet = stopIds.map { arr =>
      val iter = Source.fromFile("times.csv").getLines().drop(1)
      val cols = iter.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
      cols.find(col => col(1) == arr(0) && col(2) == time) match {
        case Some(value) => value(0) //String type
        case None => NotFound(s"No Vehicle available at the given time ${time}")
      }
    }

    val lineIter = Source.fromFile("lines.csv").getLines().drop(1)
    val lineCols = lineIter.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
    lineCols.find(_(0) == valueWhichImTryingToGet ).getOrElse("No vechile can be found with the given information")
  }
```

Also any improvements in the code?

one more thing I noticed is that If I do the length/size check on iterator **stopIds** it exhausts the iterator and no further processing can happen. So how can I find if the first filter returned 0?

Comment: yeah, im juust using it for testing. I want `Some(value)` this `value`

Comment: I think you want `collectFirst`. That's like `collect` except that it stops at the first element collected.

Comment: I can think of a var outside and set it in the case with value. but still have to think of stopping the flow. and I don't know if its the right way.

Comment: but does the collect takes predicates?

Comment: `collect` takes a `PartialFunction` which `filter`s and `map`s at once.

Comment: It's not necessarily an exception as I don't want the system to stop. But in case user provides the wrong parameters I want to catch and display the message. 
The `value` is this case is `Array[String]`

Comment: You are not in a control block. Those are `for` and `while`. Here you are using `.map` metod of a collection which gives you another collection by transforming each element using the mapping method.

Comment: ok, I use collectFirst and it returns an Option but still how do I stop the iterator to executing anyfurther.

Comment: @sarveshseri  `for` is not a "control" structure in Scala - it's a syntactic sugar over map/flatMap/foreach.

Comment: @Sam `getLines` is lazily evaluated - you stop iterating = you stop reading. The only issue I see is that you aren't explicitly closing file, so there might be a dangling handler.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yes. but how do I stop iterating? is breaking the only way?
And by closing you mean in the scenario when the iterator isnt fully exhausted or otherwise as well?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Yes. But, no matter which language we convert this code to, it will not be a control block.

Comment: @sarveshseri I thought foreach is control and map is foreach under the hood except it returns. But I'll read about it.
CollectFirst and find both breakout but since there's an upper map/foreach the value still cant get out of that.

Comment: @jwvh map and for-yield returns iterators. foreach nothing. in the first case, I'd have to again iterate and find the next value.  to return a simple string I have to put it into iterator and then access it again. isn't there supposed to be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic can be expressed without breaks more or less like this (I didn't dig into domain context, as it is apparently irrelevant and you can adjust it yourself):

```
// instead of running whole code for all entries we can just check
// if value exist within some set of values
val stopIds = cols.filter(arr=> arr(1) == x && arr(2) == y).map(_(0)).toSet


Source
  .fromFile("abc.csv")
  .getLines()
  .drop(1) // drop headers
  .map { line =>
    line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
  }
  .collectFirst {
    // find first entry which has second value from stopIds set
    // and third value equal to expected time
    case _ :: id :: atTime :: _ if stopIds.contains(id) && atTime == time =>
      Vehicle(value(0), value(1))
  }
  .getOrElse {
    // if no matching value is found fall back on "not found" case
    NotFound(s"No Vehicle available at the given time ${time}")
  }
```

As a side note - I would recommend some proper CSV library here as this solution is not bulletproof, and would break if e.g. someone created a file with an escaped coma.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question/Body with context. I have to search/join in three files. To get the value I can think of making a var and breaking. 
Conversion from Iterator to Set and List respectively vs var and break. How do you weigh it?  
any improvements on the code are also welcome(I know the csv parser because of ',').

Comment: or use the iterator[Oject] returuned by map or for-yield, and then get values out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Does this get at what you're after?

```
import scala.util.{Using,Try}  //Scala 2.13.x

def findVehicle(time: String, x: String, y: String) : Try[String] =
  Using.Manager { use =>
    //open the files to be read
    val stopsFile = use(io.Source.fromFile("stops.csv"))
    val timesFile = use(io.Source.fromFile("times.csv"))
    val linesFile = use(io.Source.fromFile("lines.csv"))

    //read stops file, collect all IDs for given x & y
    val stopIds : Set[String] = 
      stopsFile.getLines().drop(1).map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
               .filter(arr => arr(1) == x && arr(2) == y)
               .map(_.head).toSet

    if (stopIds.isEmpty)
      throw new Exception(s"No stop ID for $x and $y")

    //read times file only until 1st matching time
    val lineID : String =
      timesFile.getLines().drop(1).map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
               .find(col => stopIds(col(1)) && col(2) == time)
               .fold(
      throw new Exception(s"No Vehicle at time $time")
                    )(_.head)

    //read lines file only until 1st matching line ID
    linesFile.getLines().drop(1).map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
             .find(_(0) == lineID)
             .fold(
      throw new Exception(s"No vechile found with line ID $lineID")
                  )(_(1))  //name
  }
```

Comment: I like your's idea more but the other person answered first. but what I found out that there no natural way to get out of/stop block. Have to get head value or something,

Answer (score 0):

As you question is little abstract here are my suggestions

- use break to get out of loop
- dont have to read the file for each iteration you may read once and use it so put it outside loop

  ```
  val iter = Source.fromFile("abc.csv").getLines().drop(1)
  val cols = iter.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
  import util.control.Breaks._
  val stopIds = cols.filter(arr=> arr(1) == x && arr(2) == y)
  if(stopIds.length>0) {
    stopIds.map{ arr=>
      cols.find(col=> col(1)==arr(0) && col(2)==time) match {
        case Some(value) => // your code
          break
        case None => NotFound(s"No Vehicle available at the given time ${time}")
      }
    }
  } else {
    NotFound(s"No stop found at given x=${x} and y=${y}")
  }
  ```

We can further optimize if you give sample input and output

Comment: Just don't use a `map`. You can just use a `collectFirst`, or if you really want an imparitive approach like breaking then just use a `while` loop.